# How can you reference a single output from an if else conditional in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic app with an if/else conditional. In each branch I have a compose action to create some JSON. The true branch has compose and the false compose_2. After the conditional I want to send a message to a queue with the output from either branch but how do I reference the output? I have two actions("compose") and actions("compose_2"). Is there any way I can reference the output with a single variable/property name?

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the initialize and set variables actions? You would use initialize before the if/else action and the set variable in both branches of the if/else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by using `@result()` which will return all the output of a scope (`Condition` in your case) as an array, and you can use `@coalesce` to find out the non-empty value between `Compose` and `Compose_2`.

However, I would use variable instead:

- Declare an variable before `Condition`
- Set the variable in each branch
- Reference the variable after `Condition`